# piping node.js object streams to multiple destinations is producing bizarre results -- why?

Tags: node.js, stream

When piping one transform stream to two other transform streams, occasionally I'm getting a few of the objects from one destination stream appearing in place of the proper objects in the other destination stream. In a stream of 90,000 objects, in about 1 out of 3 runs about 10 objects starting at the sequence number about 10,000 are from the wrong stream (the start position of number of anomolous objects varies). What in the world could account for such bizarre results?

The setup:

```
sourceStream.pipe(processingStream1).pipe(check1);
processingStream1.pipe(check2).pipe(destinationStream1);
processingStream1.pipe(processingStream2).pipe(destinationStream2);
```

The sourceStream is a transform stream fed by a file read. The two destination streams are transform streams leading to file writes. Both the file read and file write are through the fs streaming API. All the streams rely on node.js automatic backpressure in piping.

Occasionally objects from processingStream2 are leaking into destinationStream1, as described above.

The checking streams (check1 a sink, check2 a passthrough) show the anomalous objects exist in the stream through check2 but not in the stream into check1.

The file reads and writes are of text (csv) files. I'm using Node.js version 8.6 on Windows 7 (though deserved, please don't throw rocks at me for the latter).

Suggestions on how to better isolate the problem also welcomed. The anomoly is structured enought that it doesn't seem like a generic memory leak, but not consistent enough to be a code error. I'm mystified.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! processingStream2 modifies the object in the stream coming through it (actually modifies a property of a sub-object). Apparently you can't count on the order of the pipes as controlling the order in changes in the streamed objects. Very occassionally, after sending the source objects through processingStream2, the input object to processingStream2 goes into processingStream1 via node internals. Probably as part of some optimization under the hood.

Lesson learned: don't change the input streamed object when piping to multiple destinations, even if you think you're making the change downstream. May you never have to learn this lesson the hard way!